# Importance of the new line "\n" in Java networking

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Well, I need a clarify of what is **the importance of the "\n" new line** in the String variable here

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Whois{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Socket soc = new Socket("whois.internic.net",43);
            InputStream in = soc.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = soc.getOutputStream();
            String url = "http://www.infiniteskills.com\n";
            byte[] buffer = url.getBytes();
            out.write(buffer);
            int c;
            while((c = in.read()) != -1){
                    System.out.print((char)c);  
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Note :- without the \n the program doesn't work correctly and no output.

Comment: What protocol are you sending it with?

Comment: Might help to know what `out` and `in`are.

Comment: okay I will edit the post

Comment: In some protocols (such as HTTP) newlines are significant (they say when the header is finished). If you don't send two new lines after the last header, it doesn't finish.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis HTTP

Comment: Are you sure? The protocol being used in your example code is WHOIS, not HTTP. Completely different.

Comment: @duskwuff Sorry may be I am confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newline has no importance in Java networking.

However it does have importance in many *protocols,* many of which are based on the 'Telnet Terminal' convention of `\r\n` as the line terminator. This certainly includes SMTP, FTP, HTTP, and Telnet itself.

It also has importance for the `BufferedReader.readLine()` method. You will find hundreds of questions here about `readLine()` blocking forever, to which the answer is 'you are reading lines but you are not writing lines', i.e. just sending a string with no line terminator. This does not constitute a complete line, so `readLine()` doesn't return it.

Comment: @AlvinBunk This answer answers the question which is explicitly stated both in the title and in the body of the question. What is more, the original poster has accepted it as the correct answer. Your comment therefore reads a little strangely.

Comment: Sorry @EJP, yes your post is constructive. I didn't have a comment to your posting though - or at least I don't see it here. It might have been good to tell the OP a bit about Whois though.

Comment: While implementing on Golang using it's built-in `net` library, I followed a few tutorials that on the first message to the client, there was a `\n` at the end of the message. I thought it's just some none sense. But I realized after some head scratching, it seems like I do need that first message with the `\n`. These answers cleared my skepticism about my conclusion

Answer (score 4):

TCP port 43 is the WHOIS protocol explained here on Wikipedia:
[Whois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS)

If you see the article is says: *Send a single "command line", ending with CRLF.*
That's why you need the newline in your code.

Comment: If it says `CRLF` then doesn't he need to end with `\r\n`?  Or is the `\r` being inserted by some other layer?

Comment: Actually @ajb is right, it probably needs to be `\r\n` to be fully compliant with the Whois protocol. The fact that it works with `\n` probably just depends on the server implementation. In this case, the server responds to `\n` (which is probably a good thing). Scorpion, I wasn't implying any problems, just giving you a reference for the Whois protocol so you can understand how to troubleshoot. I hope my answer helps!